# Pushing an option in a nested form with Symfony 2

Tags: forms, service, nested, symfony-2.1, nested-forms

I'm working on a form using select boxes. These boxes stand for scales which defer among countries.

Therefore, I created a service which generates custom values to feed the select box according to the user's preferences.This works fine with a first level form:

Controller code:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new formType, $entity, array(

     // Getting the service    
     'myScales'     => $this->get('myBnd.scales'),

     // Getting user's scale preference
     'scalesLocale'  => $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getScaleLng(),

     ));
```

Then, I got all I need in the formType to display the customized select:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {

    $scaleSelect = array();        
    // Here is a custom code using $options['myScales'] and $options[scalesLocale']
    // This builds the relevant $scaleSelect

    // ....

$builder
        ->add('scale', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => $scaleSelect
        ))
        ->add('subscale', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new subType,
            'prototype' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
        ))
```

Then I need to define the nested subType. It also requires a customed select box. How can I send it the variable `$scaleSelect` in order to generate the (same) appropriate select box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quickest option that crosses my mind:

```
      ->add('subscale', 'collection', array(
           'type' => new Subtype($scaleSelect),
           'prototype' => true,
           'allow_add' => true,
           'allow_delete' => true,
       ))
```

then in your Subtype class:

```
     function __construct($choices) {
         $this->choices = $choices;
     }
```

after that you can access your passed choices in buildform with $this->choices.
Hope it helps.

Comment: What if the subtype is passed as a string (->add('subscale', 'collection', ['type' => 'mySubType', ...]) )? I.e. it is possible to turn custom form types into services (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html). In this case we cannot pass anything to the constructor... any work around?